# Form submission blocking issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I'm new here in terms of asking questions, but I have read many articles/questions/answers for quite some time now. My question is about part of a code that got me stuck for some time now.

So in my project I've got a registration form that has an JS validation and server side validation. Now what I wanted to do is disable form submitting before the JS validation is ok and I've set some conditions for it to be like that. Now the problem occured when those conditions were met. I used this line to stop form from submiting:

```
$('.memberReg').on('submit',function(){return false;});
```

In a situation like this for instance:

```
if(response.okText == 'SUCCESS' && response.warning == null ) 
                        {

                            $('label[for="email"]').addClass("success");
                            $('label[for="email"]').append("<span>    is not yet registered!</span>");  
                            console.log(result);
                        }else 
                            {

                                $('label[for="email"]').addClass("error");
                                $('label[for="email"]').append("<span>   is already taken!</span>");
                                $('.memberReg').on('submit',function(){return false;});

                            }
```

What happens here  is that I do block the form from submiting, but it is blocked entirely, even when the other conditions are met. In this example even with correct email you cannot submit anymore.

I have tried using a variable with true-false statements that would make a validForm() function submit the form, but the function starts looping and it is still not enabling the form.

I also tried using return true for the form submit in the valid email part, still the same effect.

Anyone knows how to block it only on a certain condition without blocking it  entirely so that the user has to refresh if he wants to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out, after a few test runs it works smoothly, so I will post it in case someone else might have the same problem.

So at start I used:

```
$('.memberReg').on('submit',function(){return false;});
```

Which was overwriting the submit handler as one of the good people told me in one of his answers. So I tried changing my approach to the way I want to implement it and used:

```
$( ".memeberReg" ).submit(function( event ) {
 if ( condition ) { 
       //successfulValidationCode
        return;
    } 
      //errorCode
      event.preventDefault();
})
```

Under conditions I am checking the variables that I set in my field validations and in case of a bad input i use   `event.preventDefault();` to block the form again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're overwriting the submit handler, and once it is overwritten, it is gone until the page is reloaded. I would question this approach entirely to be honest; you shouldn't have to overwrite the submit handler to prevent the form being submitted.

By the way, you're using JavaScript validation, not AJAX validation. AJAX is the process of sending a request to the server, and potentially receiving a result, *without refreshing the page*

Comment: Yeah, I just realize what I wrote, thanks buddy.

What approach do you  suggest?

Would it work the same if I would use:

`$( ".memeberReg" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if ( condition ) {
    //successful validation code
    return;
  }
 
 //error code
  event.preventDefault();
});`

Comment: It could work, but it's hard to say without seeing more code. There are many approaches to client-side validation ;)

Comment: Thanks for the insight Dan, I think i figured it out ^_^  Gonna make a few more test runs and post it as an answer to my question :)

As far as more code goes , it's kinda hard to provide due to contract code secrecy I have to respect  :(

Comment: It's often the way, but it can be a good thing because it forces you to make a cut-down version that you can share, and doing this often highlights the issue

Comment: Very true. It's funny how sometimes the smallest mistakes can lose you many hours and then someone just comes in and states the obvious. The relief after job done is great. Thanks for the tips ;)